# MySQL как установить и делать запросы на C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, mysqlconnector

Я хочу изучать `SQL`, но запросы в админ-программе скучно)
Я решил это делать на `С++`.

Нашел библиотеку коннектор. Но вот как мне сам `MySQL` установить? `OpenServer`?

`OpenServer` это не только для `php`?) Я просто в `БД` новичок можно сказать)

`Вопрос`: Как мне установить `MySQL` и запустить сервер?

Comment: Например скачать на dev.mysql.com или в unix/linux системах воспользоваться готовым пакетом вашего дистрибутива

Comment: @Mike а нельзя ли OpenServer?

Comment: Можно. Но зачем ради MySQL ставить целый набор разных программ. Веб-сервер и php вам нужны ?

Comment: @Mike ну вообще нет)

Comment: Ну тогда установите MariaDB